# How to fix the text format in a input text?

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery and I would like the create an input the to let the user digit the date `'mm-dd-yyyy'`.

example: when the user digit 12(the number of the month) I would like to show the `-` automatically. is it possible?

Comment: I still haven't found a decent masking solution for web-based input.  Every one I encounter has some small quirk; and there are a LOT of quirks out there.  If you're going to use masking, it's best to use an existing solution: e.g. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    if(val.length >= 2)
        val = val.substring(0,2) + '-' + val.substring(2); 
    if(val.length >= 5)
        val = val.substring(0,5) + '-' + val.substring(5); 
    if(val.length > 10)
        val = val.substring(0,10);
    $(this).val(val);
});
```

Here's a live demo :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/AUAJ3/

### UPDATE :

Some optimisations :

- You shouldn't stop the `keydown`/`keyup` events if one of the "special" keys are pressed (by special I mean in this case *delete*, *backspace* and arrow-keys) that allow you to change the current value
- You should check on `keydown` if the pressed key is a valid number (0-9) and stop the event id it isn't
- Bind the correction algorithm to the `change` event too

```
$('input')  
    .change(function(e){
        $(this).val(formatDate($(this).val()));
    })
    .keyup(function(e){
         if(isSpecialKey(e.keyCode))
            return true;
          $(this).val(formatDate($(this).val()));
    })
    .keydown(function(e){
        if(isSpecialKey(e.keyCode))
            return true;
        var k = e.charCode || e.which;
        var keyVal = String.fromCharCode(k);
        if(!/[0-9]/.test(keyVal) || $(this).val().length > 9)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
    });

function formatDate(val){
    val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    if(val.length >= 2)
        val = val.substring(0,2) + '-' + val.substring(2); 
    if(val.length >= 5)
        val = val.substring(0,5) + '-' + val.substring(5); 
    if(val.length > 10)
        val = val.substring(0,10);
    return val;
}

function isSpecialKey(k){
    for(var i in KEY)
        if(KEY[i] == k)
            return true;
    return false;
}

var KEY = {
    'delete' : 46,
    'backspace' : 8,
    'left' : 37,
    'right' : 39,
    'up' : 38,
    'down' : 40
}
```

Here's a live demo :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/AUAJ3/2/

### SECOND UPDATE:

You should inform the user on the date format that your input field requires.
See [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/AUAJ3/3/) for this new feature.

Comment: Perfect soloution. Also takes into account multiple presses at once. voted up!

Comment: @gion_13, the problem that the focus is set at the end of the text...if i need to change a number inside a must delete all the text and rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/g8KSg/ :)

```
$('#checkval').keyup( function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    // check for first 2 chars
    if(value.length === 2) {
        value += "-";
        $(this).val(value);
    }

    // check for first 4 + "-"
    if(value.length === 5) {
        value += "-";
        $(this).val(value);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $("#mytextbox").attr('maxlength', 10);       
        $('#mytextbox').keyup(function(e){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value.length == 2)
            {
                $(this).val(function(index, val) {
                        return val + '-';
                    });
            }
            if(value.length == 5)
            {
                $(this).val(function(index, val) {
                        return val + '-';
                    });
            }

        });
}) ;
```

And html

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox">
```

And live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MQtrq/3/)

Edit :
To set max length use this

```
$("#mytextbox").attr('maxlength', 10);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MQtrq/4/)

Comment: it does not work I can write: 12-12-222222222222 an infinite text. I need fixed length.